# radio button change event does not fire

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery 1.6.2 now radio button checked does not fire. I could do for long time

```
<input id="DocumentNotesList_d20bb499-012f-487e-aba8-391e2adf5cd5__IsPrivate" type="radio" value="True" name="DocumentNotesList[d20bb499-012f-487e-aba8-391e2adf5cd5].IsPrivate" data-val-required="The IsPrivate field is required." data-val="true">

 $('input[type=radio], input[value=True]:radio').change(function () {

 });
```

and

```
<input id="DocumentNotesList_e3d0d4d1-c135-4e8e-aa12-333eafaef403__IsPrivate" type="radio" value="False" name="DocumentNotesList[e3d0d4d1-c135-4e8e-aa12-333eafaef403].IsPrivate" checked="checked">
```

Comment: jQuery 1.6.2 is _four years_ old. You have to update. Is your code in a `$(document).ready()` statement?

Comment: added missing parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put your code within `script` tag:

```
   <script>
        $('input:radio[value="True"]').change(function () {
            alert('selected');
        })
   </script>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rx7h2onx/1/

Comment: plz see my question again,i have two radio button

Comment: @govindaghimre not sure if you updated the question properly. You can use this `$('input:radio[value="True"]')` see my update.